How to Retrieve Last/Current Signed-In User Information When Migrating from Legacy Google Auth to CredentialManager?
Problem :

I have migrated GoogleSignIn Legacy to the New Credential Manager Library.

Now In the Old App, I have checked every time before performing any operation is the user SignIn Already?  But In CredentialManager How to check?

I used Sign in with Google button flow (https://developer.android.com/identity/sign-in/credential-manager-siwg#trigger-siwg )

Old Code for retrieving Last SignIn account details


GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(activity);

Google Email ID : googleSignInAccount.getEmail()
Google Profile photo: googleSignInAccount.getPhotoUrl()
Google Name: googleSignInAccount.getDisplayName()
Google token Id: googleSignInAccount.getId()


Now, In New Credential Manager which method gives the last-current Signed-In User Info?
Like in the Old Method "GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(activity)" given.

The main concern is "How to retrieve LastSignedInAccountusing CredentialManager?"



Why do you need to check n before each operation? User signs up to your app/service; you get user info in the ID Token, you create "an account" for your user in your database and user is signed in to your app until they explicitly sign-out from your app, using possibly a sign-out button that you have in your app (which you can observe if used).  Can you explain why such flow is not working for you?

@AliNaddaf Hi, As I have mentioned in question I'm not storing sign-in tokens so, I need to check. In the Updated app I will add a store token but what about Old users who already signing in to the App?

@Ali Naddaf users can also sign out via https://myaccount.google.com/

@AliNaddaf Let me clear all this stuff, I have added GoogleDrive API for the app data folder and store users' files in their drive with the app private folder (AppDataFolder). And for that Google sign-in is required. But I'm not storing any token or details of the signed-in user, I will manage only with the "LastSignInAccount" method. If the method does not send me Data means the user is not signing in, if sent means the User is already signed in. But in new Migrations How can I manage? How do I know that the user is already signed in?

Let me clarify this: you don't need users to be "signed-in" in order to use the Authorization APIs. you can simply call the Authorization APIs and that, after user selects an account and gives consent, returns an access token to you and you can use that to access user's drive. Then, in subsequent calls, you call the same Authorization APIs again; if user has already given you the consent, that call should return an access token to you again (without prompting the user, so it will be silent) and you can access user's drive again. Does that flow work for you?

@AliNaddaf Okay I got your point. Let me try with this flow. Thank you!

@AliNaddaf Hi Ali, we are using authorization API only, and we would like to let user know, which Google Drive account he is currently login to (Since the user might have multiple accounts). Previously, this can be done easily via GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount. Right now, what is the solution if we were using Authorization API? Thanks.
